# Initializing class variable from dropdown value

Tags: c#, class, case

I have two forms on my winforms c# application.

The first form is a login form which performs authentication against active directory and a number of authorization checks that the user should be allowed to continue.  On the form there is also a dropdown with options:

```
Environment:

Development
Staging
Production
```

Once the user is vetted I have the following being set prior to hiding the login form and showing the main app form:

```
Globals.environment = ((string)this.cmboEnvironment.SelectedItem).ToLower();
```

Globals.cs

```
public partial class Globals
{
    // A flag which denotes the environment that the tool should run against (staging/development/production)
    public static string environment;
    public static string server;
    static Globals()
    {
        switch (environment)
        {
            case "development":
                server = "Dev-Server";
                break;
            case "staging":
                server = "Staging-Server";
                break;
            case "production":
                server = "Production-Server";
                break;
            default:
                server = "Dev-Server";
                break;
        }
   }
}
```

What I am finding is that the server value is always set to Dev-Server no matter which drop down I select.

I think what's happening is the Globals object is being instantiated prior to the call to set the environment value, and thus the case statement is defaulting to the "default:" case.

I can't figure out how to set the environment before all the other globals values get populated. Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: Static constructors get called prior to setting the attribute.  Remove the check from the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
public partial class Globals
{
    // A flag which denotes the environment that the tool should run against (staging/development/production)
    public static string environment;
    public static string server;


    public static void SetEnvironment(string env)
    {
        environment = env;
        switch (env)
        {
            case "development":
                server = "Dev-Server";
                break;
            case "staging":
                server = "Staging-Server";
                break;
            case "production":
                server = "Production-Server";
                break;
            default:
                server = "Dev-Server";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and then :

```
Globals.SetEnvironment(((string)this.cmboEnvironment.SelectedItem).ToLower());
```

Comment: This works - thank you. @un-lucky I believe it works because we don't call the case statement until we've set the environment using the SetEnvironment method.

Comment: the problem is that the static constructor are the first thing called before even running the main method, that's why he has to move the server init code from the static constructor to a static method that will init server field with the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct the `default` case is executing all the time, this is because, the input `environment` is not matching with anyone of the given case( switch performs case-sensitive comparison for the given expression and the cases). you need to change the `case` as same as what given in the DropDown or use `.ToLower()` like the following:

```
switch (environment.ToLower())
{
        case "development":
            server = "Dev-Server";
            break;
        case "staging":
            server = "Staging-Server";
            break;
        case "production":
            server = "Production-Server";
            break;
        default:
            server = "Dev-Server";
            break;
}
```

Comment: I'm lower casing the dropdown value here: Globals.environment = ((string)this.cmboEnvironment.SelectedItem).ToLower();